# SQLite: Search and sum similar values

Tags: database, sqlite, sum

I have this table:

```
pupil_id | mark | month | year
```

Data:

```
01 | 4 | February | 2015
02 | 6 | September| 2014
01 | 3 | February | 2015 
02 | 5 | September| 2014
```

The desired results for `pupil_id | month | year | sum(mark)` are:

```
01 | February | 2015 | 7
02 | September | 2014 | 11
```

How can I here sum the similar values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GROUP BY` should give you the result you want.

```
SELECT pupil_id, month, year, SUM(mark)
FROM marks
GROUP BY pupil_id, month, year
```

Comment: Use `GROUP BY pupil_id, month, year`

Comment: Doesn't  work so, the sum(mark) column has the same result like mark column.

Comment: Show us sample input data and your desired output so that we may end this droll game of comment tag.